# Common lisp gray streams

Tags: stream, common-lisp

Is there a tutorial on how to use gray streams?

I want to create a class that reads from a file while looking for a specific set of bytes. My initial thought was to use gray streams, but could not find any starting information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw43/CLIM/html/climguide-336.htm) useful. In SBCL, gray streams are in package `:GRAY`.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the examples in the SBCL manual can help you for a start?

http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Gray-Streams-examples